# Send List as parameter in a method

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have the below List:

```
List<Item> items = getItems (id);
```

This is returning the list of `itemid`, `name` and `ids`.
But I want to fetch `itemid` from this list and send as an argument to my another method like below:

```
List<ItemTotals> itemTotals = this.ItemTotalDAO.findVHFItemTotalsByItemIds(List, budgetYear);
```

So I am unable to print the list of item id and to pass it as an argument. How can I do that?

Comment: In your getItems() method, return only List that contains itemids

Comment: It is actually List <Items> items=getitems(id) which is returning the 3 columns like itemid,name and ids

Comment: should that be "List itemTotals = this.ItemTotalDAO.findVHFItemTotalsByItemIds(items, budgetYear);

Comment: @JohnBollinger Since you removed the existing generic types, I rolled back your destructive edit. Please take more care next time, for example by checking the *"side-by-side markdown"*.

Comment: In: this.ItemTotalDAO.findVHFItemTotalsByItemIds(List, budgetYear); WHAT IS LIST? Instead of passing "List" try passing what you want, that means replace "List" with Item.getItemId() or Item.someMethodInTheItemDTOThatReturnsItemID().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this might help you.

```
List<Item> items = getItems (id);
List<Integer> itemIds = getItemIds(items);
List<ItemTotals> itemTotals = this.ItemTotalDAO.findVHFItemTotalsByItemIds(itemIds, budgetYear);
```

The getItemIds(items) definition goes here.

```
List<Integer> getItemIds(List<Item> items) {
    List<Integer> itemIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Item item : items) {
       itemIds.add(item.getItemID());
    }
 return itemIds;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that really solved my problem i did few changes and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

I used another list like below:

```
List<Long> itemIdList = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (Item vith : items) {
    itemIdList.add(vith.getItemId());
    System.out.println("itemid list is " + itemIdList);
}
```